# Force putty to use right click to paste, on linux

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, putty

Is there a way to force `putty` to allow to paste with right-click, on Zorin OS (Ubuntu based).

I like the windows behaviour, where selected stuff is pasted, when right click is pressed.

Comment: out of curiosity, why in the world would you use putty if you're not on Windows?

Comment: Putty also supports serial, telnet and some other stuff all in one program. I have posted a relevant answer if the reason you're using putty is not for SSH.

Comment: I use putty because I'm used to it and I like it's interface and behavior on Windows. It's linux...must there be something I can do to make it to work like I want, regardless of putty supporting it or not. I use a laptop and I can't just use the "middle button"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user
[@ateijelo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/35006/ateijelo) said
in [their answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/569503/72304) it's
not possible to use "Compromise (Middle extends, Right pastes)" on
Unix because it's not implemented.  I don't know why isn't it, you
should ask Putty developers about that, most probably nobody has even
requested it. But, thanks to the nature of open source you can always
modify the program's source code to suit your needs and use it. The
following patch will modify the default behavior of right click and
will make it paste the text:

```
diff --git a/unix/gtkwin.c b/unix/gtkwin.c
index 5660ee9..4f2ec2b 100644
--- a/unix/gtkwin.c
+++ b/unix/gtkwin.c
@@ -447,7 +447,7 @@ static Mouse_Button translate_button(Mouse_Button button)
     if (button == MBT_MIDDLE)
         return MBT_PASTE;
     if (button == MBT_RIGHT)
-        return MBT_EXTEND;
+        return MBT_PASTE;
     return 0;                          /* shouldn't happen */
 }

diff --git a/unix/uxsftpserver.c b/unix/uxsftpserver.c
index a90344e..6fab0ba 100644
--- a/unix/uxsftpserver.c
+++ b/unix/uxsftpserver.c
@@ -412,16 +412,6 @@ static void uss_fstat(SftpServer *srv, SftpReplyBuilder *reply,
     }
 }

-#if !HAVE_FUTIMES
-static inline int futimes(int fd, const struct timeval tv[2])
-{
-    /* If the OS doesn't support futimes(3) then we have to pretend it
-     * always returns failure */
-    errno = EINVAL;
-    return -1;
-}
-#endif
-
 /*
  * The guts of setstat and fsetstat, macroised so that they can call
  * fchown(fd,...) or chown(path,...) depending on parameters.
```

You have to get Putty source code, apply the patch and re-build
Putty.  It's a simple process though.

Clone Putty repository:

```
git clone git://git.tartarus.org/simon/putty.git && cd putty
```

Save the patch I pasted above to MBT_PASTE.patch and apply it (if it fails download patch directly from http://drabczyk.org/MTB_PASTE.patch):

```
git apply MTB_PASTE.patch
```

Build Putty:

```
$ cd unix
$ ../mkfiles.pl  && ../mkauto.sh
$ make -j$(nproc) -f Makefile.gtk LDFLAGS="-Wl,--no-as-needed,-ldl"
```

Building takes only 6 seconds on my machine.  Start the newly built
Putty binary:

```
./putty
```

You should see all of your saved sessions and settings just as if you
stared Putty installed system-wide using your distro's package
manager.  You should now be able to paste selected text with right
click.  If you don't want to recompile Putty on your own and you
*trust* me you can get a precompiled binary from here
http://drabczyk.org/putty.

This method has its disadvantages of course.  The change I've
introduced has not formally accepted by Putty developers what means
you're now using a
[fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(software_development)).  If
you replace Putty binary installed with your distro's package manager
with this it will be replaced each time you update Putty using your
distro's package manager (and sometimes you may not even realize that
Putty is being updated, for example when running a massive system
upgrade).  Alternatively, you can put your fork of Putty elsewhere,
for example in `~/bin` and prepend `~/bin` to your `$PATH` so that the
fork will be picked before system-wide Putty binary. I also don't
know which unwanted side effects can this small change cause, if any.

I was also thinking about using `xdotool` but I'm not sure if you run
X or Wayland and I think that modifying a single line in the source
code is all in all easier.

Comment: I'm getting error: corrupt patch at line 13 when trying your patch. I copied and pasted using vi...

Comment: Sorry, I can't paste it correctly here. Get it from http://drabczyk.org/MTB_PASTE.patch

Comment: Still having the same issue idk how

Comment: Did you do `wget http://drabczyk.org/MTB_PASTE.patch && git apply  MTB_PASTE.patch` in `putty` directory?

Comment: Yes...still saying the same error

Comment: What does `git status` say?

Comment: Nevermind... I forgot to delete my old file and wget didn't overwrite it. Will test the rest

Comment: I had to do apt install automake dh-autoreconf -y to be able to run mkauto.sh... and your last command to build it fails with about gtk.h file not being found or something. Can you list everything it should be installed to be sucessful

Comment: The usual thing to do (with regards with where to drop a modified binary) is place it in usr/local/bin.

Comment: Post the exact error command you get and not *or something*. I don't use Ubuntu so I don't know what should be installed, probably something related to GTK.

Comment: `--cflags: 1: --cflags: gtk-config: not found`

Comment: Now I'm also getting a ` recipe for target 'gtkdlg.o' failed`

Comment: On Ubuntu you have to do `apt-get install libgtk-3-dev` but see updated answer - we should use a different repository as the one on Github is only a mirror and is not kept up to date with the upstream. I've also modified `MTB_PASTE.patch`. Ideally, remove old `putty` directory or rename it to `putty.bak` and do everything once again.

Comment: If you're using a Debian based system (you mentioned apt install), then do `apt-get source putty`, make your changes and then do `dpkg-buildpackage --no-sign` the source directory. That should take care of all the dependencies and compilation steps and give you a nice .deb file in the parent directory.

Comment: Great work on the patch, but is there any reason why `futimes()` gets removed?

Comment: @ateijelo I'm getting this error trying to do what you said: E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list` the answer is good...just need to get this few issues fixed so I can accept it. Thanks everyone

Comment: @undercatapplaudsMonica: it causes `../unix/uxsftpserver.c:416:19: error: static declaration of 'futimes' follows non-static declaration`, both on my host Slackware 14.2 system with glibc 2.23 and in official Ubuntu docker image with glibc 2.27. I guess there is a bug somewhere in the build system.

Comment: @Freedo That kind of stuff is very easy to google, see e.g. [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/857433/296757).

Comment: so in the end I Just used his built binary...because I kept having issues trying to compile it myself. as the last make command just wouldn't work...and if I went the apt source way I have no idea how to do the git patch on it...so I accepted it and all but I'd prefer if there was a easy and complete way to compile yourself on Ubuntu based distros...

Comment: is it possible to make selecting text on putty copy to my clipboard too?

Comment: @Freedo this should work out of the box in X https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_selection

Comment: It's not working for me :(

Comment: How are you pasting selected text and to what programs? You can use `xsel` to check contents of PRIMARY clipboard. It's working for me.

Answer (score 2):

Hold CTRL + right click into putty window will allow you to select "Paste from CLIPBOARD" or "Copy to CLIPBOARD" from a menu. Close enough?

Comment: So simple and easy ! :)

Answer (score 1):

The MS-Windows/dos/cmd terminal has the feature of paste-last-selection bound to right click (if enabled). Putty may be doing the same.

Many X11 programs have this bound to the middle click. However no need to select the selection with the additional click. This will work with openssh.

While I have no idea why anyone would use PuTTY outside of Microsoft's Windows (It is an ssh for MS-Windows to help people escape, and not as good as open-ssh-client in konsole ). I have confirmed that the middle-click does paste into the PuTTY terminal on Debian 10:

```
Putty Release 0.70
Build platform: 64-bit Unix (GTK + X11)
Compiler: gcc 8.3.0
Compiled against GTK version 3.24.5
Source commit: 3cd10509a51edf5a21cdc80aabf7e6a934522d47
```

Comment: I recommend konsole + openssh-client (`ssh`).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, based on the answer by @arkadiusz-drabczyk, I'll flesh out how to make your own version of PuTTY on Debian:

Enable source URIs in your apt source files. This can be done with UIs in many distros:

[image]

or by making sure you have lines in /etc/apt/sources.list that look like this:

```
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free
```

Once you have those, follow these steps:

```bsh
mkdir putty
cd putty
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wget
sudo apt-get build-dep putty
apt-get source putty
cd putty-0.70
sed -i 's/return MBT_EXTEND/return MBT_PASTE/' unix/gtkwin.c
dpkg-buildpackage -b --no-sign
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i putty_0.70-6_amd64.deb putty-tools_0.70-6_amd64.deb
```

Check where it says `0.70` and change for the right version for you. This should get your modified PuTTy installed.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know how to force putty to use the right-click on Linux, I suggest (like other answers) using a better program if at all possible.

Everyone here has assumed you're using putty for SSH, if that's the case I would recommend using your standard terminal and the SSH program.

If however you're using a serial interface I would recommend using the screen terminal emulator instead. For example I launch it like this `sudo --group dialout screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200` to interact with our serial devices. With this approach you only get the immediate window though, if you need to access the scrollback you'll have to use the hotkey Ctrl+a, [ then  you can use your arrow keys to navigate the history. Simply press Esc to exit copy mode and return to the current line.

Using your standard terminal allows you to copy and paste as your would with any other terminal program via the right click or hotkeys if supported by your terminal. With screen you also get a whole bunch of features that may/not be useful depending on what you need to do.

For Telnet and the other communications that putty supports I'm sure Linux has plenty of similar alternatives available.

If this doesn't cover your use case I suggest modifying your question to actually let us know what you're doing with putty so we can best advise.

Comment: Don't run as root (sudo without --group). There is no need to and it is dangerous. Instead: become a member of the `dialout` group, serial ports are usually in this group; or add the serial port to a group, that you are a member of.

Comment: Given that this is just my PC, and that I know that screen to a USB shouldn't effect the system it doesn't really matter that much for me... But I take your point and I didn't know about the `--group` option so that's good to know for future.

I'm happy to keep the edit as it is good advice for security!

Answer (score 0):

I don't bring good news. The docs [say this](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.73/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-mouseshift):

> Windows often only has two mouse buttons, so when run on Windows, PuTTY is configurable. In PuTTY's default configuration (‘Compromise’), the right button pastes, and the middle button (if you have one) extends a selection.
>
> If you have a three-button mouse and you are already used to the xterm arrangement, you can select it using the ‘Action of mouse buttons’ control.

and indeed, the config has an additional section:

[image]

And even if you set the `MouseIsXterm=1` option in the config file of a saved session, PuTTY only pays attention to it when running in Windows. Search for `mouse_is_xterm` in the source file [windows.c](https://github.com/github/putty/blob/master/windows/window.c).

If you're using Linux frequently, I recommend to train your muscle memory to middle button paste, and when you use PuTTY in Windows, do the same. It's the standard in all Linux terminals, and you'll be fighting an uphill battle if you try to change it. Some terminals may allow it, but most won't.

Comment: It's linux. Must be a way to trick the system to do the behavior I and millions of people want. I use a laptop and it's not easy to just use a "middle button"

Comment: @Freedo not an answer to your question - but I just use the keyboard binding (shift+ins) when working on systems with only two mouse buttons available.

Comment: @Freedo: you can also try to modify Putty's source code and re-compile it as a last resort

Comment: XTerm at least permits changine the mapping - but beware ... mouse mapping via Xdefaults  demands a bit of perseverance.